# Java: How can I "break" a switch-case after a specific time?

Tags: java, libgdx, switch-statement, break

I have a method that renders items.

The problem I'm having is that  I want the switch-case to break after 4.1 seconds. I don't want to use `Thread.sleep`, because it would freeze the entire screen on runtime.

This is what I tried, but it doesn't work:

```
private void drawItems(){
       itemSelected = randomInt.getValue3();
       switch (itemSelected){
           case 0: if (!Obstacle.case0) {
               doSomething();
           }
               new java.util.Timer().schedule(
                       new java.util.TimerTask() {
                           public void run() {
                                break;
                           }
                       },
                       4100
               );
// other cases
```

I want to break it because otherwise more than 1 item is being rendered on the screen, but the problem is that "break" needs to be outside switch or loop.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but would it make sense to run drawing routines in another thread, then interrupt it after 4.1 seconds?

Comment: What does `batcher.draw` do? When does it return?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov It just renders the item and once Obstacle.case0 == true it removes the item after collision. nsandersen I don't have experiences with threads, so I don't really know what it has to look like..

Comment: Thing is here is that `break;` only works once it is "encountered" by a running thread. That means it will break the switch only once `doSomething()` is completed, and not before. As it's written now, even `Timer.schedule` is executed after `doSomething()` is done. You will need to read about threading and interrupts, and specifics are both on `doSomething()` implementation and the loop in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplest form, something like:

```
public class DrawingThread extends Thread {
    private boolean goon = true;

    public void run() { 
        //Drawing routine.. stop if goon is no longer true
    }

    public void requestStop() {
        goon = false;
    }
 }
```

Then in your main method/driver class etc:

```
 DrawingThread dThread = new DrawingThread();
 dThread.start();
 //Other things, for instance try { Thread.sleep(4100) } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
 dThread.requestStop();
```

[Some pointers at Jenkov.com](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/creating-and-starting-threads.html), also in Oracle's java documentation. If that works well for you, look into reusing Thread objects, perhaps something under point 26 in the sidebar on that page would be useful.

Comment: Extending `Thread` is an antipattern. You'll need `goon` to be volatile.

Comment: I agree it is probably better to implement the Runnable interface than extending Thread. Whether the boolean variable goon needs to be volatile or not depends on what we do exactly. Just stopping execution by changing it, does not require it to be volatile.

Comment: @nsanderson The boolean `goon` is shared between threads, is it not?

Comment: Yes, but (intended to be) set from one controlling thread only.